# Bootstrap responsive table - dropdown in header

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have [this table](https://jsfiddle.net/xgvLgadu/) and I have problem with dropdown in `<th></th>`. When table is in `<div class="table-responsive">`, dropdown is in table. I need to show it over table.

Thanks for advices.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check this https://jsfiddle.net/xgvLgadu/1/
I use `overflow:visible` on `table` and `th/tr`.
And I change `z-index` of `.dropdown-menu` to 9999
Cheers,

Comment: There isn't solution. When table will have only one row, problem is back

Comment: Yes it is.. the problem with one row is that the body don't expand and the dropdown cant show in a little height of body/table... check this again, i push the table to don't limit the visible area. https://jsfiddle.net/xgvLgadu/2/

Comment: Ok, its better. But when I will have under the table any content, iwill be displayed 500px bellow.

Comment: Put less height.. just the same dropdown's height

Comment: Ok I updated our [example](https://jsfiddle.net/xgvLgadu/3/). Table has only one row and between this row and table border is much free space. It is not good solution because allways will be under the table free space. It is other solution?